# openrowset sql export data to excel (Dynamic Column Names)

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel, openrowset

I would like to export the data from sql to an Excel file. I was able to export the data to a predefined file, but I am trying to create a file and export data to that file.

I am  executing a stored procedure which returns different column each time and I would like to export the result into the excel file and email it.

How can I do this?

Comment: does it have to be an excel file or is .csv fine as well?

Comment: Please add your trying code with static column names ;).